# Find project root relative to the active buffer

Tags: vimscript, filesystem

I can use the `finddir` function to find a parent folder that contains a `.git` folder (project root), like this:

```
let dir = finddir('.git/..', ';')
```

However, this only finds project roots that are parent folders of Vim's current working directory, which is usually the directory Vim was started in. I would like to find project roots that are parent folders of the location of the currently active buffer.

**Edit**: I tried

```
let dir = finddir('.git/..', expand('%').';')
```

But this always returns the current directory for some reason.

Comment: check [:h file-searching](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#file-searching) and [:h expand()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29)

Answer (score 11):

After following dedowsdi's instructions, it turns out you just need to do:

```
let dir = finddir('.git/..', expand('%:p:h').';')
```

`expand(%)` expands into the path of the current file (excluding the filename).