# From a Neovim extension, how to detect project root?

Tags: neovim, lua

I am learning to write Neovim extensions.

Let's name it `my-extension`.

From my extension, I want to detect the presence of a `.my-extension.json` at the root of the project.

This is because I want to store different information in that file, that I will grab from the extension.

The extension is written in Lua.

If I write it full Lua, it would look like:

```lua
local function get_nearest_git_dir()
  -- Use `package.loaded` to avoid redundant calculations
  if not package.loaded["nearest_git_dir"] then
    local current_dir = package.cwd
    local found = false
    while not found and current_dir ~= "" do
      if fs.access(current_dir .. "/.git", "r") then
        found = true
      else
        current_dir = string.sub(current_dir, 0, string.len(current_dir) - string.len(string.match(current_dir, "^[^/]+")))
      end
    end
    if found then
      package.loaded["nearest_git_dir"] = string.sub(current_dir, 1, string.len(current_dir) - string.len(package.cwd))
    else
      package.loaded["nearest_git_dir"] = nil
    end
  end
  return package.loaded["nearest_git_dir"]
end

local relative_git_dir = get_nearest_git_dir()

if relative_git_dir then
  print("Relative path to nearest git directory:", relative_git_dir)
else
  print("No .git directory found in the current directory or its ancestors.")
end
```

Is there a Vim function that would be shorter?

Comment: See `:help findfile()`, i think, which can do upward searches

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20605/10604

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a Vim function that would be shorter?

In vim, you can use `findfile` or `finddir`.

Find `.git` directory upwards:

```
let gitDir = finddir('.git', expand("%:p") . ";")
if !empty(gitDir)
    " .git directory is found
    echo fnamemodify(gitDir, ":h")
endif
```

Find `.my-extension.json` file up directory structure:

```
let fileAtRoot = findfile('.my-extension.json', expand("%:p") . ";")
if !empty(fileAtRoot)
    echo fnamemodify(fileAtRoot, ":p")
endif
```